# Membership not extended to all related contacts

Tags: civimember, relationships

Because a membership type was in use, I wasn't able to edit its relationship properties via the CiviCRM GUI. So I did it in MySQL (by editing membership_type_id and membership_direction fields in civicrm_membership_type).

I thought I created all related records the civicrm_membership table (each contact needs their own, even if the membership is inherited), but I must have missed some or encountered a bug because after doing this edit, I had to go through and Edit then Save some membership records in CiviCRM itself to fix them.

However this didn't work for everybody, and **records with multiple relationships only passed on memberships to one of the two related records.** Again, this may have been the result of an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions below took place inside the CiviCRM GUI:

For most, I had to disable and re-enable all relationships and subsequently edit and save the membership.

In a few cases, even this didn't work. For those records, I also edited the membership and specified a number of allowed related records before saving (I also subsequently went back in and cleared out that number with no ill effects).

Comment: Recording this here for my own sanity - this is not the first time I've found this Q&A so for my future self (hello me) or other searchers: One install I encountered had two identically named relationship types, but only one of those was the one allowed by the membership type.